# Fedora 21: Getting "libprocps.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on ps

Tags: fedora, ps

I have Fedora 21, which is a fedup from Fedora 20. My problem is that whenever I am using `ps` commaand, I am getting `/usr/bin/dpkgd/ps: error while loading shared libraries: 
libprocps.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

This code was working perfectly when I had Fedora 20 installed. While doing Fedup, I got a bunch of
`ldconfig: /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1 is not a symbolic link`
message, but the fedup went fine.

Here are the output of the commands which might be relevant:

```
$ which ps
/bin/ps

$ type ps
ps is /bin/ps

$ ldd /bin/ps
not a dynamic executable

$ ldd /usr/bin/dpkgd/ps
    inux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77f7000)
    libprocps.so.1 => not found
    libsystemd-login.so.0 => /lib/libsystemd-login.so.0 (0xb77ae000)                                                                                                                                      
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x467c7000)                                                                                                                                                            
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x465f9000)                                                                                                                                                              
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x46a72000)                                                                                                                                                            
    libdw.so.1 => /lib/libdw.so.1 (0x47816000)                                                                                                                                                            
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x46854000)                                                                                                                                                      
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x467ce000)                                                                                                                                                  
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x465ce000)                                                                                                                                                                       
    libelf.so.1 => /lib/libelf.so.1 (0x47695000)                                                                                                                                                          
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x46edd000)                                                                                                                                                        
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib/libbz2.so.1 (0x46a7d000)                                                                                                                                                          
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x467eb000)
```

If I do a `sudo yum reinstall procps`, the problem goes away, even if the output of `ldd` does not change. But after restarting the computer, the problem returns. What could be the permanent solution of this problem?

Comment: For starters, don't use `which`.  Use `type`.  Can you add `type ps` to your output in the question?

Comment: Here is the output: ps is /bin/ps

Comment: Second, do you expect there to be a `/usr/bin/dpkgd` directory?  Searching for that suggests it might be a rootkit or exploit.

Comment: Oops! I did not know that. I though anything with "dpkg.." is related to Debian based distros. I wondered where it came from. How do I clean it?

Comment: Also I get get a bunch of [Starting](null) and [Started] (null) at the time of system startup. Can that be a rookit too?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246710&p=13137196#post13137196 makes me suspect an exploit.  I'd suggest unplugging your computer from the network and investigating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24465/discussion-between-rocker1985-and-mikel).

Comment: @Rocker1985 how did you finally resolve it?

Comment: @Projjol Did a dnf system-upgrade to Feora 22.